# show non-leading tabs as ^I

Tags: listchars

Sometimes I need to use a literal tab that isn't in a leading position (for instance in a Makefile or occasionally in a shell script). It would be nice if tabs in those contexts were displayed in a fixed-width way instead of having a width that depends on the locations of tab stops.

If you `set list` and `set listchars=`, then all tabs show up as `^I`, a literal representation of the tab byte. I'm not sure whether `vim` itself or the terminal emulator is responsible for displaying tabs this way.

Is it possible to show all non-leading tabs and only non-leading tabs as `^I`?

Is it possible to make the behavior of the tab character dependent on where the tab character is within the line?

for instance `set listchars=tab:12`, will make tabs display the same way regardless of whether they appear as part of the leading indentation of the line or somewhere in the "middle" of the line, namely the first character corresponding to the tab will be `1` and `2`s will be used to pad to the tab stop.

For instance, `"\t\ta\tb\tc"` is displayed as follows:

```
1222222212222222a1222222b1222222c
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to direct vim to display the first two tabs differently from the last two. I'd "\t\ta\tb\tc" to be displayed as

```
1222222212222222a^Ib^Ic
```

Comment: What do you mean "non-leading"? Give an example text of what you're seeing and what you want to see. Along with the values of `set list` and `set listchars=`

Comment: Oh, no, it is not possible with `listchars`. But you might be able to do this with `:h conceal` Sorry, I'm of no help there.